# Rewarded ads not working properly in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, admob, ads, admob-rewardedvideoad

Here is mine MainActivity -

```
class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var btn1: Button? = null
    private var mRewardedAd: RewardedAd? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)



        btn1 = findViewById<View>(R.id.button1) as Button

        btn1?.setOnClickListener {

            loadAd()
            showAd()

            if (mRewardedAd != null) {
                val intent: Intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                Toast.makeText(this, " Ad completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun showAd() {
        if (mRewardedAd != null) {
            mRewardedAd?.show(this, OnUserEarnedRewardListener() {
                fun onUserEarnedReward(rewardItem: RewardItem) {
                    var rewardAmount = rewardItem.getAmount()
                    var rewardType = rewardItem.getType()
                    Log.d(TAG, "User earned the reward.")
                    Toast.makeText(this, "User earned the reward.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            })
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "The rewarded ad wasn't ready yet.")
            Toast.makeText(this, "The rewarded ad wasn't ready yet.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }


    private fun loadAd() {
        var adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()

        RewardedAd.load(
            this,
            "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
            adRequest,
            object : RewardedAdLoadCallback() {
                override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                    Log.d(TAG, adError?.message)
                    mRewardedAd = null
                }

                override fun onAdLoaded(rewardedAd: RewardedAd) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Ad was loaded.")
                    mRewardedAd = rewardedAd
                }
            })
    }
}
```

MainActivity.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="224dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#9C27B0"
        android:text="Button main Screen"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.589"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Reward ad is not loading everything. Sometime when I press back then ads come. No idea How it work. I want when I press button in MainActivity , then It will show rewarded ads & after it goes to next Activity. please help me on this.

I am using Android Intent to go to nextActivity. sometimes its go to nextActivity without showing Ads. rewarded ads not loading everytime. Rightnow I am checking with text ads.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `loadAd()` and `showAd()` at the same time, when the user taps on the button.

You need to have an ad in the memory to show it.
You have to call `loadAd()` just after you initialize your `MobileAds` SDK, so you always have a loaded ad in the memory, which you can show later on a button click or any other event.

Remove `loadAd()` call from `btn1?.setOnClickListener` and move it to `onCreate()`, you also have to intitialize `MobileAds` SDK

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        MobileAds.initialize(this) {}
        loadAd()

        //here goes your remaining code
}
```

Inside `showAd()` method, set the `fullScreenContentCallback`, after `null` check of `mRewarededAd`, to load a new ad, after the user watches a rewarded ad.

```
mRewardedAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object : FullScreenContentCallback() {
    override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
      Log.d(TAG, "Ad was dismissed.")
      // Don't forget to set the ad reference to null so you
      // don't show the ad a second time.
      mRewardedAd = null

      // Reload rewarded ad
      loadAd()
    }

    override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError?) {
      Log.d(TAG, "Ad failed to show.")
      // Don't forget to set the ad reference to null so you
      // don't show the ad a second time.
      mRewardedAd = null
    }

    override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
      Log.d(TAG, "Ad showed fullscreen content.")
      // Called when ad is dismissed.
    }
  }
```